# Combining multiple rows into a comma delimited list in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table StudentName(id,name) that looks like this:

```
id | name  
++++++++  
1 | alex    
1 | adam    
1 | adnan       
2 | ben   
2 | bush           
3 | cris  
4 | daisi   
4 | diana
```

And I'd like to make a new table like this:

```
id | name   
+++++++++++    
1 | alex, adam, adnan    
2 | ben, bush        
3 | cris     
4 | daisi, diana
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: First off no you wouldn't. Storing data that way is incredibly silly. Second off if they are different values then why do they share an ID?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `group_concat` function is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT   id, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY id
```